# sendRedirect() does NOT throw IllegalStateException with Servlet 3.0 under GlassFish 3.1.1

Tags: exception, servlets, web-applications, glassfish

I have a servlet with an overridden `doGet` method in a Dynamic Web App 3.0 targeted to GlassFish 3.1.

I'm studying for [OCEJWCD](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=527) exam and trying to memorize which circumstances throw which exceptions.

Due to Tomcat 6.0 only supporting Servlet 2.5 API, I have to use Glassfish 3 and I'm very confused with following situation.

Numerous old [sources](http://www.examulator.com/moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=449) state that:

> A response is committed as soon as the servlet starts to write
>   anything to the output stream. If you attempt a re-direct after the
>   response is committed you will receive an IllegalStateException error.

However Servlet 3.0 Final specification Section 5.3 states:

> If data has been written to the response buffer, but not returned to
>   the client (i.e. the response is not committed), the data in the
>   response buffer must be cleared and replaced with the data set by
>   these methods. If the response is committed, these methods must throw
>   an IllegalStateException

What I want to know is, considering the `PrintWriter.print()` is **committing** the response, why don't these lines throw `IllegalStateException`?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = "http://someurl.com/";
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("This will be written into response buffer");
    response.sendRedirect(url); // sendRedirect() after writing into buffer
}
```

I have to note that, I am able to fetch exceptions from GlassFish server log, I can clearly see that `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher().forward(req,res);` followed by a `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(url);` does indeed throw an `IllegalStateException` in GlassFish container.

Comment: *"Due to Tomcat 7.0 only supporting Servlet 2.5 API"* This is untrue. Tomcat 7.0 supports Servlet 3.0. Perhaps you're confusing with Tomcat 6.0? See also http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: I was trying to refer to Tomcat 6.0. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that `PrintWriter.print()` *may* commit the response. This happens if the buffer is full or if there's no buffering at all. You can check its size by calling `ServletResponse.getBufferSize()`.

`ServletResponse.flushBuffer()` or `PrintWriter.flush()` *will definitely* commit the response.

So if `PrintWriter.print()` was committing the response, then the `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()` would indeed throw an `IllegalStateException`.

See also Servlet Specification, section *5.1 Buffering*.

And btw., there's no `RequestDispatcher.dispatch()`. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've been reading too many specs lately thus I'm making up method names. Will fix now.